# Hibernate transaction committed in case of exception encountered

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, transactions

I had created a service layer in which my method was having the transactional annotation over it in the following manner :

```
@Transactional
void a() {
     User user = new User(1, "Abc", "Delhi");
     userDao.save(user);

     A a = null;
     a.toString(); //null pointer exception being encountered here.
}
```

The transaction should have been rolled back and the user's details should not have been persisted to the db, but it is not happening.

Comment: Transactions do roll back with the provided code. See [this sample](https://github.com/manish-in-java/stackoverflow-questions/tree/master/43883841) with the provided code. Since you are finding transactions not rolling back, transactions are either not enabled or not being applied. There can be many reasons for this and the exact cause can be determined only by looking at the full failing code.

Answer (score 1):

Run time exceptions will roll back the transaction by default. I don't know exactly in hibernate, but in eclipse link implementation of JPA, we  can specify the rollback = true/false for the application exceptions as shown below.

@ApplicationException(inherited = true, rollback = true)

try similar configuration change.

you can also rollback in the catch block something like below

catch(Exception e) {

```
entityManger.getTransaction().rollback();
```

}